# Shorter way for find() query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to find if cell with provided coordinates exists in DB.
Is there a shorter way to create this query?

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    coors: {
        x: String,
        y: String
    }
});

// coors = {x:'1', y:'2'};
schema.statics.is_cell_exists = function (coors, callback){
    var Cell = this;

    var coors_x = {};
    var coors_y = {};
    coors_x['coors'] = {x: coors.x};
    coors_y['coors'] = {y: coors.y};

    var query = { $and: [coors_x, coors_y] };

    Cell.find( query ).exec(...);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just seems you have some unnecessary variables, etc. You can simply use `dot notation` to get inside that "coors" object and search on it.

```
Cell.find({ $and : [{ 'coors.x' : coors.x }, { 'coors.y' : coors.y }] })
```